Сохранить случайно генерируемые разными переменными числа в список одним элементом
Код генерирует случайные ip-адреса и ip-блок к ним, следом выводя получившийся случайный ip-адрес:
def ip_generation():
    global ip_generation_ipv4
    global ip_generation2_ipv4
    global ip_generation3_ipv4
    global ip_generation4_ipv4
    global subnet_generation

    ip_generation_ipv4 = randint(0, 255)
    ip_generation2_ipv4 = randint(0, 255)
    ip_generation3_ipv4 = randint(0, 255)
    ip_generation4_ipv4 = randint(0, 255)
    subnet_generation = randint(0, 24)

    print(f"{ip_generation_ipv4}.{ip_generation2_ipv4}.{ip_generation3_ipv4}.{ip_generation4_ipv4}/{subnet_generation}")
ip_generation()

Проблема:
Необходимо, чтобы те данные, которые выводятся, сохранялись в список как отдельные элементы, чтобы в итоге список состоял из этих ip
['192.76.0.0/24', '210.92.71.85/16'] и т.д.


Можно через генератор списка сделать - короче и проще.
Код:
from random import randint

def generate_ip_list(count):
    return [f"{randint(0, 255)}.{randint(0, 255)}.{randint(0, 255)}.{randint(0, 255)}/{randint(0, 24)}" for _ in range(count)]

ip_list = generate_ip_list(5)  
print(ip_list)

Вывод:
['26.200.64.10/15', '219.19.99.251/19', '74.235.28.27/20', '158.115.167.206/0', '86.81.220.204/15']

